# Fetch API error handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch-api

I want to display error message from my API, problem is that I can't reach that error if I check for `response.ok`, it returns Fetch error, not the one from API..

If I don't use `if(response.ok)...` it returns the error from API but it dispatches the success action.

Here is the example, login action:

```js
export const signIn = data => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ 
    type: SIGN_IN
    }) 
  fetch(API_URL+'/login', { 
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
   body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then( response => {
    if (!response.ok) { throw response }
    return response.json()  //we only get here if there is no error
  })
  .then( json => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, payload: json
    }),
    localStorage.setItem("token", 'Bearer '+json.token)
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(json.user))
  })
  .catch( err => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_FAILED, payload: err
    })
  })
    
}
```

This is the code for action that dispatches the right message but as success action, not as failed one..

```js
export const signIn = data => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ 
    type: SIGN_IN
    }) 
  fetch(API_URL+'/login', { 
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
   body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then( response => response.json())
  .then( json => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, payload: json
    }),
    localStorage.setItem("token", 'Bearer '+json.token)
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(json.user))
  })
  .catch( err => {
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_IN_FAILED, payload: err
    })
  })
    
}
```

Comment: you should get that error in your catch block. can you show your `err` object?

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203#issuecomment-143347675

Answer (score 31):

With the following solution one can handle **JSON API error, Generic API error** and **Generic fetch error**

```
fetch("api/v1/demo", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "data": "demo"
    })
})
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return Promise.reject(response);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if (typeof error.json === "function") {
            error.json().then(jsonError => {
                console.log("Json error from API");
                console.log(jsonError);
            }).catch(genericError => {
                console.log("Generic error from API");
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Fetch error");
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 19):

according to [This Article](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/) :

> [Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful), the `fetch()` API only rejects a promise when
>
> > “a network
> >     error is encountered, although this usually means permissions issues
> >     or similar.”
>
> Basically `fetch()` will only reject a promise if the user
>   is offline, or some unlikely networking error occurs, such a DNS
>   lookup failure.

then, you can use this part of code to use non-network error handlings and  make your code more readable

```
function handleErrors(response) {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.status);
    return response;
}

fetch("API URL")
    // handle network err/success
    .then(handleErrors)
    // use response of network on fetch Promise resolve
    .then(response => console.log("ok") )
    // handle fetch Promise error
    .catch(error => console.log(error) );
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question((

Comment: @AndreasGelever Yes !!! and I don't know why this answer got three +1 :D but it has an indirect answer in itself ;)

Comment: `throw Error(response.status)` should be `throw new Error(response.status)`

Answer (score 17):

In order to extract API message from server in case of some error, you have to use the following idiom (which doesn't lie on the surface though), see [link](https://gist.github.com/odewahn/5a5eeb23279eed6a80d7798fdb47fe91)

```
     fetch("http://localhost:8090/test/error", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(result => {
            //Here body is not ready yet, throw promise
            if (!result.ok) throw result;
            return result.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            //Successful request processing
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(error => {
            //Here is still promise
            console.log(error);
            error.json().then((body) => {
                //Here is already the payload from API
                console.log(body);
            });
        })
```

Verbose - yes!, but does exactly what is needed.

Comment: Not working. It tells me : "error.json is not a function"

Comment: @fi11222 That's bc this answer doesn't properly handle when `fetch()` itself throws an Error, like if the user is offline, or a networking error occurs, such as a DNS lookup failure. When that happens, there will be no `json` property on the `error` object. The `error` object will actually be a `TypeError` that goes directly to `catch` without stopping at any of the `.then`s. There are numerous ways to handle this, one is checking if `json` exists on `error`, another is `if (error instanceof TypeError)`. That tells you if it was `fetch` that threw an `Error` or you just got a non-2xx response.