# Handling 500 and other errors when requesting multiple urls using fetch and promise all

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I am attempting to scrape news articles from a site using fetch and promise all.  Example found here

- [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710768/how-can-i-fetch-an-array-of-urls-with-promise-all)

Here is the code I am using.

```
        var openArticles = function(urlArray){

              Promise.all(urlArray.map(u=>fetch(u))).then(responses =>
                Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.text()))
                ).then(function(html){
                  console.log(html[0])
                 
              })
         };
```

I am not too familiar with arrow function expressions and am having a difficult time with adding error handling for 500 and timeout errors.  I tried putting code in try catch block but that did not help, and I am not sure where or how to enter if statement to check response status.  Is there a way to rewrite this using standard function name() format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle errors with promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800010/how-do-i-handle-errors-with-promises)

Comment: To be honest - No - not very helpful.

Comment: Just add `.catch(() => {/* code here */});` after the `.then()`...

Comment: This was the first thing I tried.  I tested with both then statements, as well as after the fetch.  Neither of these caught the error.

Comment: Sorry; [`fetch` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) - _"A `fetch()` promise does not reject on HTTP errors (`404`, etc.). Instead, a `then() handler must check the `Response.ok` and/or `Response.status` properties."_

Comment: Yes, I have used that method before, the problem is "where" to insert it in a function with this style syntax.

Comment: See the [first example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples) and there is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330795/fetch-api-error-handling)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is solution for now.  Sorry it's ugly syntax,  I'm sure there's a better way to write this.

```
Promise.all(urls.map(u=>fetch(u).then((response) =>{
   if(response.status != 200){
     console.log(response.status);
     // do something
    return;
  }
  else{
   return response;
  }
 }))).then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.text())) 
).then(function(html){
 //do something else
})
```

Basically I had been adding the "then" statement in the wrong position.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Instead of checking for the status code, you should check either `response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300` or just [`response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok). Every status code between 200-299 (inclusive) is a successful status. IMO, a few of the 300s are also "successful". You can read more about [status codes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I actually need to check for 500 error in order to create custom response object to return.